# Excel VBA Workbook.ChangeFileAccess

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I'm having trouble with changing the file access mode on Excel workbooks using VBA. I am using Office 2010.

I want to be able to alternate between read only and read write mode as appropriate. However it seems changing a workbook from read/write to read only and then back again as in the code below causes an automation error when trying to access any member of the workbook object.

```
Public Sub example()

Dim w As Workbook

  'open workbook with write access
  Set w = Workbooks.Open("example.xlsx", ReadOnly:=False)
  Debug.Print w.Name 'sucessfully accesses members of w

  'change file access to read only
  w.ChangeFileAccess XlFileAccess.xlReadOnly
  Debug.Print w.Name 'successfully accesses members of w

  'change file access back to read/write
  w.ChangeFileAccess XlFileAccess.xlReadWrite
  Debug.Print w.Name 'fails to access members of w with automation error

End Sub
```

I don't understand why this is the case. It is obviously perfectly possible to open a workbook as read only, change it to read write and then continue to use the object. Why is this situation different? I can find no mention of this behaviour on MSDN.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff193344.aspx

Is it possible to change between file access modes as I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've hit an interesting foible with the way that Excel changes the read/write state. In order to switch a workbook from read-only to read/write, Excel closes that workbook and opens it again. During this process, your object reference turns into something strangely broken. If you add the line:

```
  Set w = Workbooks("example.xlsx")
```

after you ChangeFileAccess to xlReadWrite then it perks up again, but it's not exactly ideal.

Chris

Comment: That certainly works but you're right it is far from ideal - in my actual code I have references scattered around that aren't easily accessible at the point where I change the state. Furthermore if you use Workbooks.Open to open a workbook as read only and then change the file access to read write the references remain valid.

Comment: Yeah, it's only the read->read/write direction that causes a reopen. :(