# Create excels with different access rights like Read/Write at run time

Tags: excel, vba

Can somebody help me for the following scenario:
I need to create copies(replicate) certain excel sheets with different security access like Read, Read and Execute, Write,Modify and Full Control(these options are visible when you check the properties of the file).

When replicating a workbook, the macro will ask user to select any one of combination of security access and when he clicks 'OK', the file should be generated with that access

Can such a scenario be achieved using Excel VBA macros. Which api or function should I use to achieve.

Can someone please point me in the right direction. It would be great help.

Comment: Yes, you can create your custom Excel Add-In file (.xla) and put it in Excel start-up directory; this Add-In should create additional custom Menu item linked to a procedure to open new Workbook with selected access rights, as you've specified.

Comment: Thanks for your reponse, but I want a simple macro to achieve the same. I want to replicate a excel file to 2-3 excel files, each having different access rights

Comment: You are welcome. Then you have to put that functionality in some 'master' Excel file (.xls), or create a template file (.xlt).

Comment: could you please show some sample function or code. i am new to excel VBA and finding it hard to understand your point

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030336/excel-vba-workbook-changefileaccess-problem

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this, it asks the questions and re-opens depending on the current read mode. This would obviously be tweaked to you needs.

**It only re-opens the file in another mode, not copies it over.**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    With ThisWorkbook
    Stop
        If .ReadOnly Then
            If MsgBox("Change to write mode?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
                .ChangeFileAccess xlReadWrite
            End If
        Else
            If MsgBox("Change to read only mode?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
                .ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly
            End If
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```